# How to remove: curl_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch records from another database server via API. Every thing works fine, the thing is, I get this warning (Warning: curl_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given). My code is as follows:

```
$URL = 'MY URL';
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($curl);
```

I need your help to remove the warning

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `$curl` is not defined. You defined your curl handle to be `$ch`, so that's what you should pass to `curl_close`.

```
curl_close($ch);
```